# How do I unlock system tools such as users and date and time

Tags: gnome, security, administration

I'm using Ubuntu Server 14.04 with Gnome and suddenly I can't unlock system settings such as Users and time & date: the unlock icon is grayed out even though I'm an administrator and terminal commands starting with sudo work just fine as does installing applications from Ubuntu Software Center.

The last change I made to the system was to install ssh client and server but I don't know if the problem started before that.

Comment: Are you part of the `sudo` group?

Comment: Yes, I am a member of sudo group.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The utilities for setting data and time work differently depending on getting a list by right clicking on the desktop which shows "Users" and "Date and Time", neither of which do not give me access for editing, and clicking on "Activities which provides a list of utilities including "Users and Groups" and "Time and Date" which I can edit.  Strange.