# 12.04 - Cannot unlock user account although it is an admin account

Tags: gnome, security, administration, policykit

I am having problems similar to these, but in this post no one managed to solve it.

[How do I unlock system tools such as users and date and time](https://askubuntu.com/questions/558939/how-do-i-unlock-system-tools-such-as-users-and-date-and-time/799497#799497)

This issued is bothering me a lot, because it also prevents me from connecting to new wireless networks (I am able to connect to the old ones I had registered in my laptop some time ago, but now it is impossible to do anything, neither via terminal). I am using 12.04, on an HP-Pavilion-dv6

I have been reading some threads on unlocking via terminal (see this for example: [Ubuntu 14.04 cannot unlock "user accounts" panel](https://askubuntu.com/questions/623569/ubuntu-14-04-cannot-unlock-user-accounts-panel)). But not even that workaround is working for me. I still can not edit anything. I suspect that unlocking my account will allow me to do all the changes I need, but I do not know what to do at this point :(

Here are two images showing what is happening (it is in Spanish, but the point is that the "Unlock" button is greyed out and I cannot click it. The message that is displayed in the User Settings screen is "System policy prevents changes...")

User settings: https://i.stack.imgur.com/H7Wa2.jpg Date: https://i.stack.imgur.com/AZCjf.jpg

It seems that at some point, something was messed up and I lost admin privileges (although my account clearly is in the admin and sudoers groups), but I do not know if gnome is not understanding that, or what the problem might be.

I really do not know where to start. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What is the output when you run `id` in a terminal?

Comment: This is the output: `uid=1000(david) gid=1000(david) grupos=1000(david),4(adm),24(cdrom),27(sudo),30(dip),46(plugdev),109(lpadmin),124(sambashare),1001(jupiter),1002(foo)`

Comment: I also tried:

`sudo echo david`

and I got the command executed

Comment: Looks okay so far. Maybe it's a PolicyKit problem, but I have no experience with that.

Comment: I agree with @ByteCommander - PolicyKit would be my first thought. Start by checking that both the polkit daemon and desktop-specific agent (e.g. polkit-gnome-authentication-agent-1) are running e.g. using `ps -ef | grep [p]olkit`

Comment: Ok. Let's check it. The output is the following:

`root      1288     1  0 20:44 ?        00:00:00 /usr/lib/policykit-1/polkitd --no-debug`