# Printers/Users Unlock button in settings disabled

Tags: printing, settings

I use gnome desktop on Ubuntu 18.04. I want to delete a printer and rename another.

I would like to use the GUI under settings and devices to administer my printers.

Help page advice me to: "Click the Unlock button in the top-right corner and enter your password."
But the Unlock button is not active. When hovering the mouse pointer above the button, it tells me that system policy prevents it, and that I should contact my system administrator.

How do I fix this?

I cannot unlock the button under users either. But in "Users Administration Tool" I am set to be administrator.

I found this post [12.04 - Cannot unlock user account although it is an admin account](https://askubuntu.com/questions/799703/12-04-cannot-unlock-user-account-although-it-is-an-admin-account)
and executed this command:

```
ps -ef | grep [p]olkit 
root       993     1  0 aug22 ?        00:00:04 /usr/lib/policykit-1/polkitd --no-debug
```

But I don't know what to look for.

Comment: I tried to do this using xrdp, as I could not access my gnome desktop locally for some reason. I rename .Xauthority and was now able to access the gnome desktop locally. Now I'm also able to administer both printers and users.

Comment: This is very frustrating and user-hostile. Secure installation of hardware drivers all you want but damn there should be an obvious way to _allow_ it! Stay inside data centers, Ubuntu. :'(

Comment: I'm having the same locked issue on 20.04.2

Comment: having the same issue too

Answer (score 3):

Does not exactly cover the problem of this question (disabled unlock button with no obvious way to enable) but for the purposes of adding/deleting/renaming a printer, you could do

```
me$ sudo su
root$ system-config-printer
```

(I believe you can straight-up `sudo system-config-printer` but something in my machine made that not work.)

From the dialog that opens you can right click on existing printers to delete or rename them.

Comment: Well for me sudo system-config-printer worked. Not the sudo su method.

Comment: This is not a permanent solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you have google chrome remote desktop installed, try uninstalling that to resolve your issue.

For me, I was having the same issue, and uninstalling the chrome remote desktop solved it. I don't know but somehow, it interferes with the settings. –

Comment: What Google chrome remote desktop have to do with the question that was asked?  How does uninstalling it solve the problem in the question?

Comment: For me, I was having the same issue, and uninstalling the chrome remote desktop solved it. I don't know but somehow, it interferes with the settings.

Answer (score 0):

On Fedora 34 at least, the software with the GUI printer settings is called `gnome-control-center`. I can confirm that starting it as root with `sudo gnome-control-center` fixed the disabled "Unlock" button and I was able to add my printer [as described in the opensource.com Common Unix Printing System (CUPS) docs](https://opensource.com/article/21/8/add-printer-linux). Exiting and re-starting the print dialog resulted in the printer showing up as a target.

Comment: You can check this yourself on your distro by watching `top` or `htop` as you start the GUI and looking for a relevant process.

Answer (score -1):

As an additional security measure, you need to log in to a physical seat to be able to unlock under the default configuration. If that is impossible, e.g. when the machine is virtual, you need to change the [policies](/var/lib/polkit-1) from `ResultActive` to `ResultAny`.

Comment: Where do I find and change these policies?